# Have an Eclipse plugin popup menu appear only when a folder is selected

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing an Eclipse plugin that takes as input some .java files. 
Since these files can be a lot and are generally contained in one package I want to show a popup menu when I right click on the containing package in the Package Explorer. 
I was able to find the following example on the web that shows the popup menu only when a .java file is selected:

```
...
<command 
   commandId = "AppAnalyzer.CodeToSrcML"
   label="Code to srcML"
   style="push"
   tooltip="Transforms all the files in the folder">
   <visibleWhen>
     <with variable="activeMenuSelection">
       <iterate ifEmpty="false">
         <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
           <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" value="*.java" />
         </adapt>
       </iterate>
     </with>
   </visibleWhen>
 </command>
...
```

(I omitted the less relevant parts of the file, full code [here](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/02/eclipse-rcp-tutorial-add-a-menu-item-to-the-popup-menu-when-right-click-a-file/) )

It works and I'm trying to modify it to fit my need but I have no idea what property should I be testing to check if the selected resource is a package. Can someone point me to which property should I be testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `adapt` use something like:

```
<or>
  <instanceof value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.IPackageFragment"/>
  <instanceof value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.IPackageFragmentRoot"/>
</or>
```